# where can I find the source code of mmap (systeml call)?

Tags: linux, mmap

I found out that glibc has mmap in mmap.S, and the code is as following:

```
...
movl 20(%esp), %ebx
cfi_rel_offset (ebx, 8)
movl 24(%esp), %ecx
movl 28(%esp), %edx
movl 32(%esp), %esi
cfi_rel_offset (esi, 4)
movl 36(%esp), %edi
cfi_rel_offset (edi, 0)
movl 40(%esp), %ebp
cfi_rel_offset (ebp, 12)
testl $0xfff, %ebp
movl $-EINVAL, %eax
jne L(skip)
shrl $12, %ebp               /* mmap2 takes the offset in pages.  */

movl $SYS_ify(mmap2), %eax  /* System call number in %eax.  */

ENTER_KERNEL                /* Do the system call trap.  */

...
```

It seems like the real part of mmap2 is in the kernel. So where can I find the source code of it?

Comment: `It seems like the real part of mmap2 is in the kernel.` - Yes, system calls are implemented by the kernel. You can find Linux kernel at kernel.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can start digging from here:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/mmap.c

search by `SYSCALL_` defines.

Comment: So if I wanted to debug it, I should have a emulator like Qemu?

Comment: Yes, `qemu` is one they to do it, also trivial `printk` can help, or something like `beaglebone` + `jtag`